# Speed up brute force for finding distribution with specific mean in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, search, combinatorics, brute-force, constraint-programming

I have the following information about grades in a course,

- There is a total of `21` students.
- 3 known grades are: one `1.3`, one `1.7` and one `1.8`.
- I know that 20 students have a grade in between `1.6` and `2.5`.
- One student has a grade in between `1.0` and `1.5` - which is obviously the grade `1.3`.
- The course average is `1.9`
- Grades are given to 1 decimal place, e.g. `2.2` or `2.3` but never `2.25`.

The following code calculates the possible grades of the other 18 students, where the grades must lay within the above constraints.

I am using a brute force way to do this, like:

```
clear all

grades = zeros([1,21])

%certain grades
grades(1) = 1.3;
grades(2) = 1.7;
grades(3) = 1.8;

a = 1.6
b = 2.59
cnt = 0;
while 1
    grades(4:end) = round(((b - a).*rand(21 - 3,1) + a)/0.1)*0.1;
    if mean(grades) == 1.9
       cnt = cnt + 1;
       savedres(cnt,:) = grades; 
    end
end
```

Firstly, I want to know how to solve this without a "brute force attack", secondly I wonder if the above method is correct?

Lastly, is there a way of knowing how many different solutions I have to expect (so I could preallocate the `savedres` vector for example)?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to calculate? I see a whole bunch of constraints and then suddenly a code. But *what* are the constraints constraining?

Comment: The possible grades of other students. Sry I forgot that sentence, I edited the question

Comment: @Wolfie Fixed the 21 issue, did not give an error cause of the assginemnt to grades. However, the issue with not breaking it under any circumstances is connected to the last question, that I do not know how many different solutions to expected. I just stop the execution once I think it has run long enough

Comment: Regarding the 3rd constraint - instead of saying "between" please use "strictly greater/less then" or "greater/less the or equal" to make it clearer to understand... Using 2.59 is pointless seeing how grades cannot have 2 decimal places...

Comment: @Wolfie Yes you are right, how should I  call this algorithm type? Would it speed up if I just choose every possible combination and test if the results match the criteria?

Comment: It would speed up in the sense that your computation time would go from "infinitely long" to "very very long"...

Comment: Side note: I would multiply everything by 10 and work with integers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A true brute force method would test every combination of grades, not just randomly pick grades.

- Grades must be `1.6 <= g <= 2.5`, giving 10 possibilities to 1d.p. 
   
  `[1.6, 1.7, 1.8, ..., 2.4, 2.5]`
- You have 18 unknown grades

This means you have 10^18 possible grade combinations. This is a lot to brute force.

---

**Reducing constraints**:

We know 3 grades: `[1.3,1.7,1.8]` and the average of 21 grades is `1.9`. So to get the average of the remaining 18 grades (`avg`):

```
(1/21) * (1.3 + 1.7 + 1.8 + avg*18) = 1.9
                       4.8 + avg*18 = 39.9
                                avg = 1.95
```

Now we can forget some of your constraints, and work within these new ones:

- 18 students
- average of `1.95`
- grades are given to 1 decimal place

---

**A smarter algorithm**

We don't want to have to brute force this, you will likely run out of patience, RAM or living breaths. You could *theoretically* get all possible combinations using

```
v = 1.6:0.1:2.5;
combs = combvec(v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v,v);
```

But this would return a 144 billion gigabyte matrix (8 bytes * 18 rows * 10^18 options) which I'd wager you can't store, let alone the time it would take to generate!

You need to limit the scope of your problem, because we can easily find one result (9 students score `1.9`, and 9 score `2.0`), and we can easily generate less trivial results by changing pairs of scores by +0.1 and -0.1, e.g.

```
[1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 2.1, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

**Generating instead of matching criteria**

So let's work out a way to *generate* satisfactory results instead of getting all possible results and seeing which fit!

You could repeatedly alter pairs by opposite amounts (ensuring grades stay bounded by `1.6` and `2.5`) to make as many as you want. You will get bored before you run out of possibilities, since there are 153 pairings (18 choose 2) and you can repeat pairings as often as you like.

A simple way to do this in MATLAB:

```
v = [repmat(1.9,1,9), repmat(2.0,1,9)];
for ii = 1:100;
    % Choose two random indices to alter
    idx = randperm(18,2);
    % Change by +0.1 and -0.1
    v(idx) = v(idx) + [0.1, -0.1];
    % Check if still within bounds, if not then revert!
    if any(v(idx) < 1.6) || any(v(idx) > 2.5)
        v(idx) = v(idx) + [-0.1, 0.1];
    end
end
% Add in previously known grades
v = [1.3, 1.7, 1.8, v];
% Random process so result different every time, e.g.
% v = [1.3,1.7,1.8,1.8,1.8,1.7,1.9,2.1,1.7,1.9,2,1.7,2.2,2,2.3,2.4,1.8,2.4,1.8,1.9,1.7]
% Test using 
disp(mean(v)); % outputs 1.9 as desired
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something that can be solved using recursion, and greatly improved (performance-wise) using [**backtracking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). I'm just providing two recursion-based solutions, one that is equivalent to the "guessing" technique appearing in the question, and the other is a somewhat more intelligent solution that discards certain guesses that would lead to failure:

```
function gradeCandidates = q45707993(methodNum)
%% Handling inputs:
if nargin < 1
  methodNum = 2;
end
%% Definitions:
N_STUD = 21;
R_AVG = 19;
G_LIM = [16 25];

%% "Initial conditions":
grades = zeros(N_STUD,1,'uint16');
grades(1:3) = [13 17 18];

%% Solution:
switch methodNum
  case 1 % "do-while" loop:    
    gradeCandidates = nextGrade(grades,4);
    % Without backtracking or a heuristic, we just test the overall validity of the  
    %   solution, and discard it entirely if it does not meet the requirements.
    while gradeCandidates(end) < G_LIM(1) || gradeCandidates(end) > G_LIM(2)
      gradeCandidates = nextGrade(grades,4);
    end
  case 2 % using a heuristic
    gradeCandidates = nextGradeH(grades,4);
    assert(mean(gradeCandidates) == R_AVG)
end
% Prepare the output:
gradeCandidates = double(gradeCandidates)/10;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Recursive functions:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "Trial and error":
function newGrades = nextGrade(currGrades,nextStud) 
  newGrades = currGrades;
  if nextStud == N_STUD % If this is the last grade, we get it by an equation on the mean
    newGrades(nextStud) = N_STUD*R_AVG-sum(newGrades);
  else % ...otherwise, just generate another grade and call the function again
    newGrades(nextStud) = randi(G_LIM);
    newGrades = nextGrade(newGrades, nextStud+1);
  end        
end

% "Heuristic":
function newGrades = nextGradeH(currGrades,nextStud)  
  newGrades = currGrades;
  if nextStud == N_STUD % If this is the last grade, we get it by an equation on the mean
    newGrades(nextStud) = N_STUD*R_AVG-sum(newGrades);
  else % ...otherwise, just generate another grade and call the function again
    newGrades(nextStud) = randi(G_LIM);
    % Heuristic that checks if a solution is even possible, by testing if the 
    % "remaining sum" is within G_LIM*(num_students_left)
    H_bounds = G_LIM*(N_STUD - nextStud) - (N_STUD*R_AVG - sum(newGrades));
    if H_bounds(1) <= 0 && H_bounds(2) >= 0
      newGrades = nextGradeH(newGrades, nextStud+1);
    else % regenerate the current grade
      newGrades = nextGradeH(newGrades, nextStud);
    end
  end        
end

end
```

I suggest you read about [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [search heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)#Search).

P.S.
Although I call the 2nd solution "heuristic-based", I'm not sure this qualifies as a heuristic, but rather as a certain technique used to prune the search tree.

Comment: **This might never terminate** because of the random grade selection and `while` loop based on a successful set being found... I assume that's what you meant by not knowing how to code it properly, but it's worth pointing out to anyone reading this!

Comment: @Wolfie while you are _theoretically_ correct, in practice - and I averaged the `timeit` output of this code for 10000 runs - it finishes after `1.2864e-04` sec. I meant that I don't know how to properly write the backtracking logic, which allows one not to throw out the entire solution but only enough so it is still solvable. Furthermore, this code can be optimized some more by transitioning to `uint8` (but for this all numbers need to be offset by the minimum grade) then offset back to avoid overflow.

Comment: Ah okay, I haven't used backtracking before or run your code, so living entirely in the realm of "*theoretically*" and learning from uncommented code and Wikipedia articles ;) interesting idea, cheers

Comment: Does this still just return one solution though, not all of the possible solutions? I have had a quick attempt to write my own function using backtracking (actually used the same "heuristic"!) but struggled with outputting all combinations. I assumed looping over the grade options where you're using `randi`  would do the trick but it doesn't appear that easy.

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, it only returns a single solution each time. Assuming that the order of grades doesn't matter, using `for` instead of `randi` will yield many solutions that are the same (which is a serious waste of computing time and/or storage), so this needs to be thought out in advance. I can't think of a way to tell how many solutions there are without finding all of them first :(

Answer (score -1):

Solution, use integer linear programming (multiply all those 1 decimals by 10 and u get integers)

```
N=21;
Avg=19;
Sum=N*Avg;%399;
f=ones(N,1);
Nc=1;
Aeq=zeros(Nc,N);
beq=zeros(Nc,1);
Aeq(1,:)=ones(1,N); beq(1)=Sum;
 Aeq(2,1)=1;beq(2)=13;
Aeq(3,2)=1;beq(3)=17;
Aeq(4,3)=1;beq(4)=18;
lb=16*ones(N,1); lb(1)=10;
ub=25*ones(N,1); ub(1)=16;
[x,fval,exitflag,output]  = intlinprog(f,N,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
disp(x')
```

Output (divide by 10 for 1 decimal grade):

```
13    17    18    16    16    16    16    16    16    16    16    16    16    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    16
```

Comment: This gives one solution out of the billions possible?

Comment: You can always add more constraints